# prove a limit about convergence of norma

Tags: real-analysis

Given $f_n:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R $ converge to 0 on norma 2. Show that:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{1\over n}\int_{-n}^n|f_n|dx=0$$
I think it has something to do with C-S inequality but i'm having troubles with it.

Comment: If you apply Cauchy-Schwarz to $\int_{-n}^n \lvert f_n\rvert\,dx$, what do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Daniel Fischer's hint it is enouh to use the  C-S inequality: $$\frac{1}{n}\int_{-n}^n|f_n(x)|dx
\leq\frac{1}{n}\big(\int_{-n}^n1^2dx\big)^{1/2}\big(\int_{-n}^n|f_n(x)|^2dx\big)^{1/2}$$

$$=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{n}}\|f_n\|_2 \leq \sqrt{2}\|f_n\|_2\rightarrow 0$$.